# Backup and Recovery Scenario

Tags: oracle, backup, recovery

Can anyone show me the step of restore and recovery of below scenario?

I have used the differential backup (cumulative) everyday.

```
RUN {
  RECOVER COPY OF DATABASE WITH TAG "whole_database_copy";
  BACKUP INCREMENTAL LEVEL 1 CUMULATIVE FOR RECOVER OF COPY WITH TAG  "whole_database_copy" DATABASE;
}
```

I have copies of all datafile, all backup sets, all redo log files with all archive logs on different media.

My system has crashed and all of my working database files are lost.

How can I do to recover my database to another server?

Regards,
Sarith

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be a programming question (the type of question this site deals with). You'll probably have better luck at an Oracle DBA forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact Oracle support right now.. Unless you can afford to lose this data, don't mess about with listening to what people on forums have to say, now is not the time to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to execute `RECOVER DATABASE` sentence?

Anyway, a very important sencence about backups: **A backup have not ended until a recovery have been tried.**